# ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" =>

Tags: jboss

- JBoss Bootstrap Environment
- JBOSS_HOME: `C:\Program Files (x86)\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final`
- JAVA: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\java`
- `JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInt
  =3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml`

---

Getting this error while starting jBoss...

```
17:14:57,087 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
17:14:57,517 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
17:14:57,637 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
17:14:59,791 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar")]) - failur
cription: "JBAS018717: No deployment content with hash a7d599d73b86a928303909b9be7573a4ea0ed28e is available in the deployment content repository for deployment 'mysql-co
or-java-5.1.24-bin.jar'. This is a fatal boot error. To correct the problem, either restart with the --admin-only switch set and use the CLI to install the missing conten
remove it from the configuration, or remove the deployment from the xml configuraiton file and restart.."
17:14:59,801 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015957: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
17:14:59,821 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015950: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" stopped in 9ms
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but an answer might be helpful for others facing the same problem, so here goes.

As the error indicates a deployment is defined in the configuration, but the content is missing (in this case a MySQL JDBC driver).

To fix such an error you have to install the missing deployment or remove it from the configuration (in this case standalone.xml).

If you read the error description, it explains both the problem and possible solutions pretty well.

> To correct the problem, either restart with the --admin-only switch set and use the CLI to install the missing conten remove it from the configuration, or remove the deployment from the xml configuraiton file and restart..

Answer (score 1):

**Just if anyone gets this in 2021 using docker image jboss/keycloak:12.0.4**

I got this exact same error in 2 scenarios, my advice is to look and find the root issue for the actual error before this one is printed in the logs. *(see 2 scenarios below)*

Error:

> keycloak_1  | 19:44:21,828 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] > (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "microprofile-metrics-smallrye")]): java.lang.NullPointerException
> keycloak_1  |   at org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.metrics-smallrye@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.metrics.MicroProfileMetricsSubsystemAdd$2.execute(MicroProfileMetricsSubsystemAdd.java:89)
> keycloak_1  |   at org.jboss.as.controller@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:1005)
> keycloak_1  |   at org.jboss.as.controller@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:744)
> keycloak_1  |   at org.jboss.as.controller@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:468)
> keycloak_1  |   at org.jboss.as.controller@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1415)
> keycloak_1  |   at org.jboss.as.controller@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:529)
> keycloak_1  |   at org.jboss.as.controller@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:515)
> keycloak_1  |   at org.jboss.as.controller@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:477)
> keycloak_1  |   at org.jboss.as.server@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:451)
> keycloak_1  |   at org.jboss.as.server@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:404)
> keycloak_1  |   at org.jboss.as.controller@13.0.3.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:416)
> keycloak_1  |   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

**Scenarios:**

**1. Database errors:**

> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
> at com.mysql.jdbc@8.0.22//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
> at com.mysql.jdbc@8.0.22//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
> at com.mysql.jdbc@8.0.22//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
> at com.mysql.jdbc@8.0.22//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
> at com.mysql.jdbc@8.0.22//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
> at com.mysql.jdbc@8.0.22//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
> at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.27.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:321)
> ... 67 more
> Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

**FIX:** Mysql connector was not installed on the server it was starting up on.

**2. KeyCloak deployment errors:**

> keycloak_1  | 19:44:21,611 FATAL [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) Error during startup: java.lang.NullPointerException
> keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@12.0.4//org.keycloak.models.jpa.RealmAdapter.getRoleNameById(RealmAdapter.java:715)

**FIX:** Fixed by updating to docker hub image `jboss/keycloak:13.0.0`